# Find and replace substring of a string in SQLite database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have an SQLite model called *Player.* Inside of this there is a column called *photo* that contains a string. For example: 84450.jpg

I would like to be able to find all the values that contain .jpg (which is actually every cell and always will be), and replace it with .png.

So 84450.jpg becomes 84450.png in my database.

I will be using a **rake** task to do this. And have tried the following with no success when running the rake task:

```
 Player.where('photo LIKE?', "%jpg%").update_all(:photo, Player.photo.gsub(/ jpg$/, "png"))
```

and

```
transform = Player.where("photo LIKE '% jpg'")
transform .find_each do |model|
  model.update_column(:photo, model.photo.gsub(/ jpg$/, "png"))
end
```

Comment: If you want to use `update_all` you need to use the [SQL REPLACE function](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-function/) as it runs a single SQL query and updates the records in the database. This would look something like  `update_all("players.photo = REPLACE(players.photo, '.jpg', '.gif')")`.

Comment: `update_all(:photo, Player.photo.gsub(/ jpg$/, "png"))` doesn't work since `photo` is not a class method and the condition would only be evaluated once and used as the value for every row in the relation.

Comment: `players = Player.where("players.photo LIKE '%.jpg'")`
`players.update_all("players.photo = REPLACE(players.photo, '.jpg, '.png')")` Gives me the error: "SQLite3::SQLException: near ".": syntax error". Is that what you meant I should do?

Comment: On SQLite I guess you would do something like `update_all("photo = REPLACE(photo, '.jpg, '.png')")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
players = Player.where("players.photo LIKE '%.jpg'")
players.each do |player|
  player.update(photo: player.photo.gsub(/.jpg/, ".png")
end
```

I included the `.` in `.jpg` and `.png` just in case you had a photo name that had the string `jpg` in it.

Comment: I would use `#find_each` instead of `#each` as it will load the records in batches and avoids the risk of exhausting the servers memory by loading the entire collection at once. Using `update_all` and doing this simple replacement in-situ will be faster by an order of magnitude though.